# Can the The golf buggy-type vehicle (ATK) outrun the storm?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I found a buggy vehicle earlier during a game in the latest version 5 release of Fortnite.

[image]

https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/fortnite-season-5-release-update-download-atk-battle-royale-guide-patch-notes-a8443586.html

It seems to move quickly (quicker than players running I think),  can it outrun the storm (assuming a straight course with no obsticles)?

Comment: The storm doesn't have a constant speed. It is a circle shrinking into a smaller circle centered on a different spot, so its speed will vary depending on how close the edge is to the new center.

Comment: So it is impossible to tell what the maximum speed of the storm is? @DanmakuGrazer

Comment: Yup. Its impossible. Sometimes its faster, and sometimes its slower

Comment: Im more than sure it can out run players. It can even damage them  if you bump a player with the buggy.

Comment: @GamerM  Is the damage significant?

Comment: I think it depends on speed. Faster speeds (Like after you make a drift) will cause more damage. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: @Simon it can't damage them directly actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explaining all of the comments in one answer, ATKs **can** outrun **certain** storms. They do move faster than players and will be able to outrun **most** storms.
This does not mean that you will be able to outrun a storm from Lazy Links to get to a circle at Dusty Divot. If the circle is centered around somewhere like Fatal Fields, or - even worse - further east or west, you will probably take some damage from the storm because you're trying to go half of the map all the way to Dusty Divot.

**tl;dr**

It can outrun **most** storms depending on the circle's position and if you're still at one side of the map.
@DanmakuGrazer explained this in his or her comment.